# Best way to upgrade FreeBSD with non generic kernel (XENHVM)

Tags: kernel, freebsd

Since manually upgrading from source (cvsup) is deprecated and the recommendation is to use freebsd-update:

What's the best way to upgrade (e.g. 9.1 to 9.2) while keeping a non-generic (XENHVM) kernel?

I'm presently using a mix between freebsd-update and manually installing from .../9.2-RELEASE/src.txz but I would like to know if anyone else as a better/faster/cleaner/easier way of doing it.

Comment: Upgrading from source is not deprecated, only the use of cvs is. Use svn (subversion) instead to synchronize your source tree and upgrade from source as usual.

Comment: As a side-note for the future: it seems that starting from 10.0, the GENERIC kernel will contain XENHVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use freebsd-update to upgrade the rest of the system and rebuild the kernel from sources as before. If the kernel has changed, freebsd-update will update the sources so you can then build your custom kernel as before.

Bear in mind that some updates will not make any kernel changes and will not require a kernel rebuild.

Comment: Also be sure to specify the XENHVM kernel configuration file... cd /usr/src && make buildkernel KERNCONF=XENHVM && make installkernel KERNCONF=XENHVM as per directions in the Makefile Also consult UPDATING prior to doing any updates.

Answer (score 3):

You could setup [your own freebsd-update server](http://people.freebsd.org/~manolis/patches/freebsd-update-server/index.html) which would allow you to use a custom kernel.

From the documentation:

> If you build your own release using the native make release procedure, the freebsd-update-server code will work from your release. As an example, you may build a release without ports or documentation and *add a custom kernel*. After removing functionality pertaining to the documentation subroutine and altering the buildworld() subroutine in scripts/build.subr, the freebsd-update-code will successfully build update code on this release.